# Why are the students' boggarts so trivial in Prisoner of Azkaban?

Tags: harry-potter

It always bugged me that during the Defense Against the Dark Arts class in their third year, every student (except for Harry and Hermione) had a boggart that took the form of something very obviously "scary." A mummy, a disembodied hand, a giant spider, etc.

> "Riddikulus!" cried Parvati.
>   A bandage unraveled at the mummy's feet; it became entangled, fell face
>   forward, and its head rolled off.
>
> [...]
>
> Crack! Where the mummy had been was a woman with floorlength black hair
>   and a skeletal, green-tinged face -- a banshee.
>
> [...]
>
> Crack! The banshee turned into a rat, which chased its tail in a circle,
>   then -- crack!- became a rattlesnake, which slithered and writhed before
>   -- crack! -- becoming a single, bloody eyeball.
>
> [...]
>
> Crack! The eyeball became a severed hand, which flipped over and began
>   to creep along the floor like a crab.
>
> [...]
>
> Crack!
>   Quite a few people screamed. A giant spider, six feet tall and covered
>   in hair, was advancing on Ron, clicking its pincers menacingly.
>
> <sub>*Prisoner of Azkaban* - page 113 - Bloomsbury - chapter 7, *The Boggart in the Wardrobe*</sub>

I understand that the kids were probably very afraid of those, but the boggart takes the form of what you **most** fear. Kids around 13 and 14 years old are old enough to have more abstract, deep fears than a single creature/animal.

I know that boggarts tend to become objects/people to represent a much deeper fear. Lupin's fear of his lycanthropy manifests itself as the moon. Harry's boggart is a dementor, which is "fear itself" and Hermione's boggart is later discovered to be McGonagall telling her she failed everything, which obviously represents her fear of failure. Still, the other students' fears seem overly simplistic. Ron is scared of spiders, yes, but I would think his deepest fear would have something to do with his feeling of inferiority or something.

How are these the students' "deepest fears"?

Comment: … what kind of answer are you expecting?

Comment: "Kids around 13 and 14 years old are old enough to have more abstract, deep fears than a single creature/animal." i don't know where you got that from but i'm still s*** scared of spiders and i'm 24, and i still fear snakes. i'm also scared of the Xenomorphs from Aliens because they have that second mouth but i'm not scared of Hollows from Bleach

Comment: Well, we don't know about the kids' past so we can't tell what's up. For all we know, perhaps there is a mummy stalking that kid every night he goes to the restroom.

Comment: @Memor-X I'm not saying real, actual fear of things like spiders isn't legitimate, I only meant that I doubt that most of the kids' deepest, innermost fears would be spiders or mummies.

Comment: This seems very subjective. Are you just looking to have a discussion on whether these fears are "valid"?

Comment: I think Lupin gave Harry too much credit on the Dementor front, to be perfectly honest. Harry was just scared of the Dementors, not fear itself.

Comment: Just found this question and I'm surprised it's closed. I'd say it can be researched. It seems suspicious indeed that the deepest fears of teenagers are not that deep. I'd say the belief that boggart can look that deep inside a person's soul is very exaggerated. Ít probably just grabs something on the surface of their consciousness. Just something enough to scare. Just look at the article on Pottermore that shows famous boggarts who took a single form to scare a lot of people. They didn't really try to go deep into someone's fears just picking a generally frightening form.

Answer (score 5):

Probably not answer worthy but what were you afraid of when you were 12 or 13 years old? I'd imagine it was something as trivial as A mean teacher or Your mother being angry perhaps.

So the answer is they are Kids.

> Kids around 13 and 14 years old are old enough to have more abstract, deep fears than a single creature/animal.

What kids do you know that have fears of money problems or death or loss? Molly has the fear of loss and so the boggart she saw transformed into her family lying dead on the floor.

Comment: any kid who grew up poor. Any kid who had a death of a close loved one. (admittedly, at 13 my fear would be like Hermione's, getting a "4 out of 5" on a test. :)

Comment: @DVK I think you can grow up poor without fear of money depending on how parents would handle everything. A close loved one of mine died and I feared death but it wasn't an ever present fear. Disappointing parents would be high on mine I imagine I can't really remember what I feared.

Comment: I grew up in a rather poor family (never went hungry or homeless though), though the only real fear I had growing up were spiders and pissing off my dad because he was extremely bipolar.

Comment: 14 year old is a formed personality with a proper knowledge of the outer world - with all it's deaths, deceases, cruelty, physical and mental sufferings. They don't need to experience it to realize the possibilities. Even an average 5 year old will be scared of his parent's death more than of spiders.

Answer (score 2):

If you notice, Boggart can become an **Object** of the fear.
The fear can be represented by boggart, but it has a limitation.

Boggart can not take a form of any abstract thing.

So It become an Object from what the students most fear.

Your question itself contains an answer

> Harry's boggart is a dementor. So what fears him most is *fear*.
>
> And Boggart can't take a form of *fear*.

Comment: Ehh, I'd argue that Lupin's fear isn't the moon itself, but a fear of the werewolf within, and turning into it, and his boggart was the moon/night sky.